# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: FIELD

Tags: java, junit, hsqldb, mybatis

I am writting junit for my project using *HSQLBD + Mybatis + Spring.*

I have sql script for create and insert.

All fields in select are present in create script still I am facing below error.
What might be the reason?

```
  org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
    ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: FIELD
    ### The error may exist in cTbl.xml
    ### The error may involve x.getyzOrders
    ### The error occurred while executing a query
    ### SQL: SELECT     fields              FROM              Table        WHERE field1 IN             (?,?,?,?,?,?)                        ORDER BY FIELD(field1 ,               ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )
    ### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: FIELD
    ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: FIELD
```

Comment: Is the syntax ```ORDER BY FIELD(...)``` intended? Normal sql syntax is ```ORDER BY FIELD1, FIELD2, ...```? Or, is ```FIELD``` a function in your schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL statement is incorrect.

If the table is called FIELDS and the columns are called FIELD1, FIELD2 etc., then a SELECT statement should look like this:

```
SELECT fields.* FROM fields WHERE field1 IN (?,?,?,?,?,?) ORDER BY field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
```

You cannot use the question symbol AFTER ORDER BY